# IOTA Whitepaper Math Section 4.1: Am I calculating this right?

Tags: iota-network, white-paper

I'm trying to craft an example going through the math equation in Section 4.1 .  I'm trying to show my work.  Can you tell me if I've got it right and if not, help correct me?

[image: 4.1 Equation]
Hx – Cumulative weight at node x – Let’s say 65
Hy – Cumulative weight at node y – Let’s say 70
Hz – Cumulative weight at node z – Let’s say 75
α – Try with 1
Pxy = exp( -1( 65 – 70 ) * ((75+74+…65)^(-1(65 – 75)) )^-1
Pxy = exp( 5) * (770^10))^-1
Pxy = 1.365e-29^5
Pxy = 4.737e-145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't look correct. Regardless of the actual numbers, you are not treating the sum as a sum but rather as a single summand. On top of that, you seem to be missing the `exp` function in a few places during your `P_xy` calculation.

Below I am pasting a sample calculation for a transaction `x` that is referenced by three other transactions `y_1`,`y_2`,`y_3`. That is, `y_i⇝x` for `i=1,2,3`.

So for example, the transition probability of going from `x` to `y_3` is ≈ 32%.

[image: SampleCalc]

Comment: Am I not iterating over y as well?  To go from z to x I have to pass through y (75, 74, 73, 72, 72, 71, 70!!!,..)  Are you saying this Sigma is not Sigma notation? http://home.windstream.net/okrebs/page136.html

Comment: Is the math supposed to be 75^( -1(65 - 75) + 74^(-1(65 - 75) .... ?

Comment: I mean, generally, there are several issues. For one, the cum weight of `x` should be larger than the one of `y`. Secondly, neither `((75+74+…65)^(-1(65 – 75)))^-1` nor `75^( -1(65 - 75) + 74^(-1(65 - 75)` has the `exp` function in it, so I am really not sure what you are calculating.

Comment: The whitepaper says put random particles on sites on the tangle and have them walk towards the target.  The walkers are defined as y approves x so so site x is somewhere earlier in the tangle and site y is a tip at the end?  The tip should have a larger weight than a previous transaction earlier no?  x should smaller than y no?

Comment: 6exp( 3 ) is the same as 6^3 or 6*6*6 or 216 no?  In my comment above I said z is 75 and I start the sigma with 75 that should be 75 ^ ( -1 ( 65 - 75) and then I add that to the next right 74 ^ (-1 (65 - 75)   ?

Comment: Earlier transactions have a higher weight (older = higher cum weight). You may want to consider asking a new (specific) question about all this, as the comment section is running out of space.

Comment: Thank you for your added math equations! I am trying to wrap my head around the details.  In your example, you are saying that we choose x as our site within the tangle and randomly walk to the tips.  In our case, there are 3 tips with the weights you specified.  But, aren't the tips supposed to have a weight of 1?  I don't understand the example now. The whitepaper says nothing about sites traversing towards sites only towards the tips.

Comment: You start at transaction x and then randomly walk towards tips (via other transactions), you don't just jump to the tips. The 3 transactions i listed are not tips, they are historic transactions referencing x. Here we model only one step of the entire walk. The weights I listed are cumulative weight, and not individual weights. Hence they are larger than 1.

Comment: So, basically the idea (which is not covered directly) is to choose how far in the past to select the main site and randomly walk towards sites (with a weight), a higher alpha means that we randomly walk towards higher weighted sites first.  We can compare the probabilities of a site going through other transactions (your y1,y2, y3)  to verify effect of the alpha.  The disadvantage of a high alpha is that we will always be selecting the highest weight branch and there may be other legitimate branches which need verification too?

Comment: That is correct.